# Rounding a double to two decimal places without using DecimalFormat

Tags: java

I wanted to know is it possible format a double to round to two decimal places with trailing zeros without using `DecimalFormat`, or importing anything for that matter? I've been trying to think of one for the past half hour and I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use String.format();

```
String s = String.format("my double: %.2f", 3.54123);
System.out.println(s);
```

or directly printf

```
System.out.printf("my double: %.2f%n", 3.54123);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about ?

```
(((int)(number * 100))/100.0F)
```

**Example**

- [ide one demo](http://ideone.com/dDVXtw)